# How to output excel sorting result into separate columns by content

Tags: excel, sorting, excel-formula, output

I have an excel column which I want to sort and output the result into a separate sheet.  I want the output to be sorted into separate columns, so that each column in the output sheet should have its own type of content, only as many times as it showed up in the original.

e.g. if the original column looks like this:

```
Right
Left
Left
Right
Right
```

I want the next sheet to show:

```
Right    Left
Right    Left
Right
```

Note, that I **Don't** want to specify what I am sorting according to, i.e. my formula will not contain "enter in this column any content that is equal to 'right'", but rather will be dynamic and will simply group whatever strings are identical into one column, etc.

How do I sort into multiple columns by content and output in a separate sheet?

Comment: Use VBA........

Comment: Depending on you version VBA will be better suited for this.

Comment: Thanks @BigBen Scott Craner.  So I take it that there is no way to do this on Excel at all?

Comment: Depending on your version it may be doable with formulas, but it'll probably be unwieldy.... It's definitely doable and possibly easier with VBA.

Comment: Yes with vba code.  It is possible with Formula but will be slower and quite labor intensive.  VBA is better suited for open ended problems(not knowing before hand the number of unique values.

Comment: Are you hoping to do this live and automatic? Doing it by hand, you can use an Advanced Sort to export a list of unique values from a column, and then you can use any formula you wish to analyze based on that list (such as ```Countifs()```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For Excel 365**

Say the first sheet is like:

[image]

In **A1** of the second sheet enter:

```
=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(Sheet1!A1:A11))
```

*(it will spill across)*

In **A2** enter:

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!$A1:$A11,Sheet1!$A1:$A11=A1)
```

and copy across.

Your required output starts in the **second** row of this second sheet.

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

If you want the column of "left"s to appear first, then use:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SORT(UNIQUE(Sheet1!A1:A11),,1))
```

in **A1** of the second sheet.

Comment: I was thinking about this approach, but did not like the needed header row.  So I started to write and INDEX/AGGREGATE to start on the second, but did not like the amount of array formula this would need.  I think with formula this is the best method, if the OP is okay with the Header Row.

Comment: @ScottCraner  I agree.........................................

Comment: If you don't want a header row, cheat and use the INDEX function to return one less than the count. eg: `=INDEX(FILTER($A$1:$A$5,C1=$A$1:$A$5),SEQUENCE(COUNTIF($A$1:$A$5,C1)-1))`  You have a header row, but it doesn't look like one.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. The Filter function gave me direction.  Next, a little more clarification and modification: How could I make each of the the outputted columns appear in a separate sheet each, with the entire row data coming along to the respective sheet?  e.g. all the rows containing 'right' appear in one sheet, and another sheet containing all the rows of 'left'?   Thanks in advance.

Comment: I also forgot to mention that I have Excel 2013, so the Filter formula doesn't seem to be recognize... any pointers?